# App crashes at a certain point after deploying with install shield

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, installshield

Greetings to all of you !

This is the second time I encounter quite a big problem and hopefuly overflow's comunity is here to the rescue !

Alright so to start this off: 
I have this program in which I make a connection to a microsoft database (Access 2003). While I debug it, everything works fine. I can access it fine and add data to it just right.

```
        int val = 0;
        int ok = 1;
        do
        {



            try
            {

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                {
                    cmd.Connection = Variables.con;
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from users";
                    using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            if (dr["us_name"].ToString() == usnT.Text)
                            {
                                ok = 0;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                if (ok == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username already taken");
                    break;
                }
                if (usnT.Text != "" && pswdT.Text != "" && ok == 1)
                {

                    pswdT.Text = pswdT.Text.ToLower();
                    string vsql = string.Format("insert into users values({0},'{1}',{2},'{3}','{4}')", id, usnT.Text, val, val, pswdT.Text);
                    OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(vsql, Variables.con);
                    vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("success");
                    vcom.Dispose();
                }
                break;

            }
            catch
            {
                id++;
            }
        } while (true);
```

However, after I deploy it with InstallShield, the app works perfectly fine except for the above piece of code. Whenever I try to add a new account to the database it crashes.

Thank you for your time and I hope you can help me troubleshoot this one. I personally consider it quite tough but I am still a beginner... Thank you !

Comment: Doubt there will be any, given the whole thing is wrapped in a catch statement which just increments a counter?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this piece of code?

Comment: Use AutoNumber field instead of a try...catch. http://www.databasedev.co.uk/autonumber.html

Comment: There are no Error Messages, no. As for what I want to achieve with this: I want to add a new account to the mdb file which I deployed as well

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Have you checked Event Viewer for messages? Access isn't the greatest product ever, but in my experience it does try to communicate when there's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can install the assembly on the same PC as Visual Studio:

Copy the PDB file to the same location as the built assembly.  Use Visual Studio to attach to the process.  Set a break point.  Then you should have a better idea as to where and what the problem is.

If you can't install on the same PC, then you can consider remote debugging (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx)

Remote debugging is quite tricky, so instead of that you could also display all the contents of any exception that's raised.  The error message and stack trace will probably give you all the information you need.